# Sorting a record array in numpy

Tags: python, python-2.7, numpy

I have an `numpy` structure array

```
import numpy as np
np.array([(0, 1, 1167606000), (0, 1, 1167606005), (0, 1, 1167606008),
       (0, 10, 1167606010), (0, 10, 1167606012), (1, 0, 1167606000),
       (1, 2, 1167606001), (1, 0, 1167606005), (1, 0, 1167606008),
       (2, 1, 1167606001), (2, 3, 1167606002), (3, 2, 1167606002),
       (3, 4, 1167606003), (4, 3, 1167606003), (4, 5, 1167606004),
       (5, 4, 1167606004), (5, 6, 1167606005), (6, 5, 1167606005),
       (6, 7, 1167606006), (7, 6, 1167606006), (7, 8, 1167606007),
       (8, 7, 1167606007), (8, 9, 1167606008), (9, 8, 1167606008),
       (9, 10, 1167606009), (10, 9, 1167606009), (10, 0, 1167606010),
       (10, 0, 1167606012)], 
      dtype=[('fr', '<i8'), ('to', '<i8'), ('time', '<i8')])
```

Is there a vectorized way to sort it first by the minimum of 'fr', 'to' and then by 'time'. Another thing is that I want to `sort` this without making any copies.

**Edit:**
The sort is not by 'fr', 'to' and 'time', but first by the minimum of 'fr' and 'to' followed by 'time'. The expected answer in the above case is

```
(0, 1, 1167606000),
(1, 0, 1167606000),
(0, 1, 1167606005),
(1, 0, 1167606005), 
(0, 1, 1167606008),
(1, 0, 1167606008),
(0, 10, 1167606010), 
(0, 10, 1167606012), 
(1, 2, 1167606001), 
(2, 1, 1167606001), 
(2, 3, 1167606002), 
(3, 2, 1167606002),
(3, 4, 1167606003), 
(4, 3, 1167606003), 

...
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can give an `order` argument to `sort`:

```
a.sort(order=['fr', 'to', 'time'])
```

---

### Sorting by minimum of two columns:

Using `lexsort`, you can sort by any set of keys.  Here, give it `a['time']` and `np.minimum(a['to'], a['fr'])` (sorts by last item first)

```
inds = np.lexsort((a['time'], np.minimum(a['to'], a['fr'])))
a = a[inds]
```

To avoid making a copy of `a` when you rearrange it, you can use `take` instead of `a = a[inds]`

```
np.take(a, inds, out=a)
```

Comment: Sorry, may be I was not clear. The sort is not by 'fr', 'to' and 'time', but minimum of 'fr' and 'to' followed by 'time'.

Comment: Oh you were clear! I just misread it!  If @Ophion undeletes their answer, it would work, for now I'll post a solution that is based on the answer they had posted before.